# loop ffmpeg command through sets of subfolders and process one folder at a time

Tags: r, bash, video, ffmpeg

I have this script on .bat file that will process any .mp4 file and create a new one with same name but adds -no-logo after the name for each video file

The problem is that I have 150 folder each has video files that I want to run this script on, is there a way to run it on each folders one by one, and do the same task

script

for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -filter:v "crop=1280:700:0:0" -c:a copy "%%~na-old.mp4"
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na-old.mp4" -vf scale=1280:720,setsar=1:1  "%%~na-no-Logo.mp4"
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do del "%%~na-old.mp4"

I don't want it to run 150 time at once, this will kill my PC, I want it to go one folder at a time

Comment: As long as you are not back-grounding the command (which is does not look like you are) then the loop should wait for each iteration to finish

Comment: You have a `bash` tag on the question, but your script looks like a `DOS` .bat file.
`R` may also have nothing to do with the question.
Please edit your tags properly to have appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

.If I understood your question correctly, I would get two "for". However it is not clear if you are using linux bash or Windows bat because you selected the bash subject but you mention using .bat.

The below is going to process one MP4 at the time anyway.  Do one folder, then the next until all is done.

```
for dir in */; do
    printf "\n\nFolder processed: ${dir}\n\n"

    count=0
    for mp4file in $dir"**/@(*.mp4); do

       ffmpeg -i "$mp4file" -y
       -loglevel error \
       -v quiet -stats \    
       place your ffmpeg command here
       count+=1

    done
    printf "\n MP4 processed count = ${count}\n"

done
```

You can continue from there.

Comment: I use windows bat, would this could run?

Comment: for dir in */; do
    printf "\n\nFolder processed: ${dir}\n\n"

    count=0
    for mp4file in $dir"**/@(*.mp4); do

       ffmpeg -i "$mp4file" -y
       -loglevel error \
       -v quiet -stats \   
   for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -filter:v "crop=1280:700:0:0" -c:a copy "%%~na-old.mp4"
   for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na-old.mp4" -vf scale=1280:720,setsar=1:1  "%%~na-no-Logo.mp4"
   for %%a in ("*.mp4") do del "%%~na-old.mp4"
       count+=1

    done
    printf "\n MP4 processed count = ${count}\n"

done

Comment: @AshrafEl-Madhoun If you use windows bat, then no this would only run on bash in linux